# Magento 2, How to implement Facebook Pixel by Category?

Tags: facebook, magento2

Facebook wants us to put relevant categories to their pixel code. Thats a part of their code im trying to implement properly:

```
fbq('track', 'ViewContent', {
content_type: 'product',
content_ids: ['<?php echo block->escapeHtml($block->getProduct()->getSku()); ?>'],
content_name: '<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getProduct()->getName()); ?>',
content_category: 'WHAT_TO_PUT_HERE?',
value: '0.50',
currency: 'USD'
```

});

We cannot use our store categories, like e.g. Black Shoes, coz Facebook use google merchant IDS. here you are list:
https://www.google.com/basepages/producttype/taxonomy-with-ids.en-US.txt

so I have to set proper id for product on magento2 store.
I guess some kind of category mapping might work. Since it sounds like a lot of code... I have come to idea, but need your help.

How would you implement this code, via Category / Design / Layout Update XML? with "Apply Design to Products" checked, So I would change

```
content_category: 'WHAT_TO_PUT_HERE?',
```

for every category; manually replacing the code.